# What's causing my window drag delay?

Tags: windows, mouse, cursor, delay

I have a strange issue: When I drag a window on its title bar with the cursor, nothing happens - the window stays there for a while until some time or cursor movement. In other words, there is some delay before anything happens.
Afterwards it snaps to the cursor and from then on, they are synced.

Observations:
- If I move quickly, there is only a tiny amount of freeze, barely noticable
- If I move slowly enough, the window never actually moves until I stop the cursor, then the window snaps to the cursor...
- If I click and hold the titlebar for 0.5-1 second, then the cursor flashes briefly and then I can move the window and it's synced pixel perfect.

These are captured here kind of in that order:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNTKZwukiyA

- Happens with all types of windows
- It's a relatively new OS install
- Mouse: Cougar 700M, 1000 Hz poll rate, but tested all the way to 125 Hz.
- Monitor: 144 Hz 1080p
- Windows 10 Pro x64, legit, up to date
- AMD R7 1700 + AMD VEGA 56
- All drivers all up to date

Any idea?
Thank you!

EDIT:

Based on suggestions,
- Done complete DDU and installing latest GPU drivers. Same issue even after reboot.
- Tried having taskmgr up while moving windows to see if there are any spikes but none.
- Strangely, while installing the AMD drivers, its **custom window** did not have that behaviour. It's a semi transparent window that isn't the default Windows style one, and does not have that problem, it moved with the cursor pixel-perfect while all other windows had the problem. Is there a Windows feature that causes it? I did check Snap feature but that's something else

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the latest video drivers? Also, what are you power management settings?

Comment: I have a suspicion, but I think this is one of those cases where a Video would greatly help. Do you have network shares on your Quick Access panel?

Comment: Do you happen to have a GSync monitor or anything?

Comment: Have you installed any sort of windows manager or application?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the comments. My monitor is Freesync 144 Hz. I have not installed any Windows manager application, either. I will record a video soon, I'm at work, thank you!

Comment: Hi, I have now updated the post with a YT link

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed strange behaviour, but it does not seem to apply to normal Windows.

It seems you are running via a TeamViewer session. In which case the graphics behaviour/oddities are caused by TeamViewer having to transmit over a network link.

- As such (remote session), this does not seem to be errant behaviour.

You may want to experiment with the following;

- Setting the TeamViewer session to performance as opposed to optimum graphics.
- Try out the same session on a faster line, perhaps on a LAN.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the assistance,

I should have clarified that this was only a remote session out of necessity, but the same happens when I'm physically at the PC.

Comment: @GaborBartal Hi. I don't have access to a AMD VEGA 56, but could you look into it's settings and look for something like 'Hardware Acceleration' ? I'm fumbling 'blind' here :-)

Comment: @GaborBartal I know the Hardware Acceleration (HA) is usually at the user end, but.. Could also try to go into your Display Settings, Advanced, and see it there are any HA setting there?

Comment: @GaborBartal If you find any such setting to change you may have to reinitialize the graphics subsystem, which is easiest done by a _full_ reboot. Do this via a SHIFT Shutdown, or preferably by this command; shutdown /r /t 5

Comment: @GaborBartal Can you also check what settings you have under; (Click on Win Icon, start typing Control Panel, open and select System, then Advanced System Settings, tab Advanced) under Performance Settings/Options ?

Comment: Thank you! Under Display settings - Advanced, it brings up my monitor details, 8-bit RGB, SDR but no other options or sign of any hardware acceleration. In my GPU's control panel, Radeon Settings, I found RGB 4:4:4, VSR: off, GPU Scaling: off, Freesync: Not supported. This last one is probably because I forgot to turn it on physically in the monitor's menu (as I found 144 Hz is sufficient in gaming without needing Freesync, but that's beside the point. The monitor is a FS one). I can only access my PC remotely for a few days but I'll try turning that on.  *to be continued*

Comment: *continued* Windows performance settings are "Let Windows choose" where everything is ticked except "Save taskbar thumbnail previews" and "Show shadows under cursor". Page size is Windows managed for C: which is an SSD and 4 other HDDs are set to None.
In Radeon Settings I found no Hardware accel related options.
In Task Mgr I see no strain of sys resources, 2-ish out of 18 GB used, 16 threads never go 100%, GPU is 1% when idling. Under Turn Windows features on and off I do have Hyper-V Management Tools on if that makes any difference (this is needed for Android Studio on Ryzen)

Comment: I have also updated my GPU driver since my post (it was up to date at that point but a new one came out), same thing

Comment: @GaborBartal Huh - what more....? I guess if you tick off the 'Show window content while dragging', the problem 'goes away'? But this would be only avoiding the problem and not solving the actual issue.. (We're gonna get slapped for commenting/discussing so much here.)

Comment: @GaborBartal I may get slapped just for suggesting this :-) but perhaps you can try a complete deinstall/reinstall of your graphics drivers? You may want to use DDU in Windows safe mode to deinstall. Then boot to normal to install. https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html

Comment: @GaborBartal The above will have to be done _at_ your PC.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I never really had issues with AMD drivers, so I haven't thought about DDU (although I've used it before on NVidia systems). I will try that, thanks. The "Show window contents while dragging" did not help after reboot, either. Also, I'm not familiar with StackExchange etiquette, should we have used a new reply posts each time?

Comment: @GaborBartal I'm not sure what to do. I'm _very_ new. Just a couple of weeks here..

Comment: @GaborBartal If you haven't done so already, run the maximum virus check available for your machine. The PC behaves as if something interferes with the screen drawing - I was thinking of the possibility of a hidden screen recorder. You do not happen to have any screen recorder/capture SW on?

Comment: Thanks, did run a virus check before, but again it's a relatively new build (doesn't mean anything with 0day viruses though, I know). I have no recording software, apart from the built-in AMD ReLive, which only activates with a hotkey so it can't be that. I am yet to do DDU so meanwhile I'm just commenting to thank for the last 2 suggestions. I will report back, cheers

Comment: @GaborBartal Another thing I'd like you to try. If we're lucky it might give us some clue as to where the problem is. Can you do the window dragging while you have Task Manager up and to the side. If you have Task Mgr open in the Performance Tab you might be lucky enough to see some spike/bottleneck in CPU/GPU/HDs/NW while the window dragging lags... If so lucky, then the trail can be followed from there.

Comment: @ruben Finally I'm able to give an update, thanks so far!

1) Done complete DDU and installing latest GPU drivers. Same issue even after reboot. 2) Tried askmgr but did not show any spikes at all. 3) Strangely, while installing the AMD drivers, its custom window did not have that behaviour. It's a semi transparent window that isn't the default Windows style one, and does not have that problem, it moved with the cursor pixel-perfect while all other windows had the problem. Is there a Windows feature that causes it? I did check Snap feature but that's something else

Comment: @GaborBartal Could you try the same on a completely fresh OS install? (If you do not want to disturb your HD you may want to try Windows To Go USB/DVD) And, is the screen card still under warranty? Maybe you have the possibility to test an identical card?

Comment: Hi, given that it's not a too annoying thing, I would not go as far as reimage or get a USB stick, so I'd rather just live with it. The graphics card is not under warranty and can't get another one as it's ~$500. In games it performs excellent still, I notice no other symptoms, it doesn't overheat etc. Besides, it only happens with the Windows 'framework' windows - if that makes sense, the default window types and works smoothly on custom windows.

Comment: @GaborBartal OK. That is understandable.